# making heatmap for warehouse by Rstudio or Python

Tags: python, r

I'm an researcher as R user

I want to make pallet rack or locate allocation for express high rotate inventory / mid,low rotate inventory

in storage pallet rack or floor

Making a heatmap will be effective for visualization and understanding

If i inventory data as 100 SKU, 10,000 inventory, ABC analyse over

I want to know basic formula making heatmap pallet rack in R or Python

pallet rack have to compose by 2 column because of worker moving

```
SKU | Inventory

1 | 1000

2 | 500

100 | 1
```

programming formula and visual data